# Команды JavaScript из адресной строки

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли как-то запретить выполнение JavaScript из адресной строки? То есть, запросы вида:

`javascript:alert('Hello World!');`

Comment: 1 вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Например, чтоб запретить какие-нибудь пакости.

Comment: Какие например? Запретить пакости для кого? для самого себя? ну пусть чувак на своей стороне делает что хочется. Какая разница?

Comment: Хотя бы `javascript:alert(document.cookie);`, хоть и есть флаг HTTPOnly.

Comment: ну и дальше что? посмотрел юзер свои куки. ок. молодец. кому он навредил?

Comment: В том и дело, что не пользователь. Допустим, он авторизовался, а доступ к рабочему месту смог получить другой человек.

Comment: Ну и зачем тогда этому самому другому человеку извращаться через адресную строку? Проще сразу в компе и прошарить. Или открыть консоль и взять всё, что надо. Открыть настройки браузера и взять все данные. Это всё равно, что человек получил доступ к ключам автомобиля пользователя, но заводит её замыкая проводки в панели >_<

Comment: Но запретить как-то возможно или нет?

Comment: Да зачем? Можешь нормальный рабочий пример привести, когда это может привести к `какой-нибудь пакости.`? Если их нет - то зачем это тогда делать? Просто "чтоб было"? Это бред